# Query Google storage to get only files in specified path

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

First of all: yes, I do realize that there is no such thing as folders in the Google Storage system. However, Google Storage has dummy folders suffixed `_$folder$`. I know that you can define `prefix` to help you filter-out some results, though, how do I define the depth? In other words, I want to get only files/_$folder$s that are under `/foo/bar` but not children of the deeper `_$folder$`s. Is that possible to do with query? PHP version of it is rather messy.